# Quarkus Rest-Client Throttling/Rate Limiting

Tags: quarkus, resteasy, quarkus-rest-client

I am using quarkus.rest-client to call an external API and want to limit the frequency of those calls to say 50 per second, such that I don't drown the external service. What is the recommended way of achieving this without a side-car approach (through code)?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `@Bulkhead` Microprofile annotation and set the maximum concurrent threads limit for the execution of your method. But, this will only work inside of one instance of your application.

[Eclipse Microprofile Documentation](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-fault-tolerance-4.0/microprofile-fault-tolerance-spec-4.0.html#bulkhead)

Example copied from the above documentation:

```java
@Bulkhead(5) // maximum 5 concurrent requests allowed
public Connection serviceA() {
   Connection conn = null;
   counterForInvokingServiceA++;
   conn = connectionService();
   return conn;
}
```

```java
// maximum 5 concurrent requests allowed, maximum 8 requests allowed in the waiting queue
@Asynchronous
@Bulkhead(value = 5, waitingTaskQueue = 8)
public Future<Connection> serviceA() {
   Connection conn = null;
   counterForInvokingServiceA++;
   conn = connectionService();
   return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(conn);
}
```

You can even set the `value` on the deploy, so you can change this parameter without a new build.

To use the `@Bulkhead`, you must add the Fault Tolerance to your project

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-fault-tolerance</artifactId>
</dependency>
```